# form with enctype="multipart/form-data" hangs on some machines

Tags: image, forms, upload

I am having a form on which I upload pictures, thus it is set with the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". The problem is on just a few machines and on any browser, after submitting the form, it keeps searching forever and finally get a 404 error.

As soon as I remove the "enctype="multipart/form-data" the form processes fine (except of course that pictures cannot be uploaded).

It works absolutely fine on my PC, anyone would have an idea what can cause this problem?

The full form tag is written this way:

```
<form method="post"  id="add-property" action="<?=BASE_URL;?>admin/cms-add-property-action.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Thanks a lot.